# AS3 - Access iPhone music library and return references to mp3(s)

Tags: actionscript-3, air, air-native-extension

I was just wondering if anyone had any ideas on how to read the music library on an iPhone from an AS3 Air application?

Would it require an Adobe Native Extension, or is there a easier way to achieve this?

Ideally what I'd like to do is just popup the phone's music player, to allow users to pick either a track, album or playist, and then return those songs to my app to add to my own playlist.

*(Also, possibly a separate question entirely, I will need to do this for Android, Windows and Mac too, if anyone has any useful tips on the most efficient way to approach this across all these platforms, it'd be hugely appreciated).*

Thanks in advance, Ted

Comment: It will require an ANE for Android and iOS. You can use `FileReference` on Mac and Windows.

Comment: Thanks Josh, I feared as much. I've just found this ANE which looks like it'll do the job nicely. If it could return playlists it'd be perfect, but hopefully it'll do:

https://github.com/richpixel/SongPickerANE

Comment: As a heads up: it may or may not work on iOS 7. A lot of the APIs, including several of the list-based APIs, changed and quite a few ANEs were broken because of it. Hopefully it will work, but make sure you test on iOS 7 to be sure.

Comment: And looking at the AS3 for that ANE, it does not appear to return a reference to the song or any data for it. Looks like it just allows the app to play the song and not much else. See the classes here https://github.com/richpixel/SongPickerANE/tree/master/SongPickerDefault/src/com/newpixel/air/nativeextensions

Comment: Thanks again Josh for the iOS 7 tips, will check it out on that when I get the chance. Re the ANE itself, I may have misled you by saying I need a 'reference' to the song. So long as I can play it (which the test app the ANE included did successfully) and have the Artist & Track that's all I'll need.

Comment: (PS - Josh, feel free to post anything sensible up as the answer to this question, and I'll mark it as accepted. Maybe the link to that ANE or something?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access nearly anything on the native side of iOS or Android, save for the Camera Roll, Camera, WebView, and Video, you need an AIR Native Extension to do it.

For accessing audio from the device's library, you can use the [SongPicker ANE](https://github.com/richpixel/SongPickerANE), which allows you to play tracks in the device's library and access basic metadata, although it won't give you access to the song data itself.