# How to select music from music album using adobe AIR in Ios device?

Tags: ios, air, adobe, flash-cs6

Am working in flash cs6 and Adobe AIR 18.I want to select music from album in ios devices using Adobe AIR.How to do that ..

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17767416/how-do-you-use-as3-to-play-and-access-your-iphone-music-library. Don't think this would be possible without an ANE.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AS3 - Access iPhone music library and return references to mp3(s)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659083/as3-access-iphone-music-library-and-return-references-to-mp3s)